# Calling an object function in a for_each lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, lambda

I'm trying to get to grips with lambdas in C++.

Here's my code (variables simplified for understanding):

```
template <typename Container>
void do_function(const Container& c, const item &w){

complex<double> a(w.x1, w.y1);
complex<double> b(w.x3, w.y3);

for_each(begin(c), end(c), [] {
    p->inner_function(a, b);
});
}
```

I know p means nothing, it's just there to illustrate what I want to do.

Essentially, I want to use this function on any kind of container (list/vector etc) which holds instances of pointers of an abstract class called Animal. These instances all have an implemention of 'inner_function(complex, complex)'.

I want to call that function on each of these in a for_each loop using lambdas in C++ 11..

The examples online are all a bit confusing though.

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: Well for starters, 'p' hasn't been declared, and apparently no 'capture mode' has been specified so it doesn't know what a and b are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems, you want to use

```
std::for_each(std::begin(c), std::end(c), [=](Animal* p) { p->inner_function(a, b); });
```

Your lambda function will need to take one argument as `std::for_each()` expects a function which can be called with the result of `*std::begin(c)`. The arguments need to be explicitly declared. You also need to choose how the arguments `a` and `b` are captured. Using `[]` means there is no captured context and you can't access any local variables at all. You can use

- `[=]` to capture all variables in the context by value.
- `[&]` to capture all variables in the context by references.
- you can override the default set up by explicitly mentioning the variables:

  - `[=,&a]` would capture `b` by value and `a` by reference.
  - `[&,b]` the same but starting with a different default
  - `[&a,b]` the same but explicitly listing all arguments.

It may be easier to use a `std::bind()` expression, actually:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::bind(&Animal::inner_function, _1, a, b));
```

Since you didn't ask a question, it is unclear what the question is, though.

Comment: This is perfect and I actually understand why now. 

I essentially wasn't sure what to use when you've used (Animal* p), and I didn't know about [=] and [&]. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If `Container` is going to be `vector<Animal*>`, `list<shared_ptr<Animal>>` etc, then I think what you want is:

```
for_each(begin(c), end(c), [&](typename Container::value_type p) {
    p->inner_function(a, b);
});
```

To also support `unique_ptr`, you might want to make it `typename Container::value_type const &p`.

Or use a "range-based for loop":

```
for(auto p : c) {
    p->inner_function(a, b);
}
```

Similarly with the option of `auto &` to allow for non-copyable `p`.

Comment: `typename Container::value_type`

Comment: @bames53: I know I should remember whether or not a lambda's parameter declaration is a context that implies a type, but I'll take your word for it :-)

Comment: You are actually going to want to use something like [&](decltype(*end(c)) p){ p->inner_function(a, b); } because you want p to be a reference (possibly to const, depending on c) in the case where c is a container of unique_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

The container must contain pointers in order to use polymorphism. I'll use smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> v;
item w;

do_function(v, w);
```

The algorithm `std::for_each` passes each element to the functor. It passes them such that the functor can take the argument either by value or reference as necessary. `unique_ptr` needs to be taken by reference:

```
for_each(begin(c), end(c), [] (std::unique_ptr<Animal> &p) {
    p->inner_function(a, b);
});
```

The functor also needs access to `a` and `b`. You can capture them explicitly:

```
[a,b] (std::unique_ptr<Animal> &p) {
```

Or as Steve Jessop suggests, just use range-based `for`, which is much simpler. With `unique_ptr` it would look like:

```
for(auto &p : c) {
    p->inner_function(a, b);
}
```